# Comparing limits of sequences, where their ratio diverges to $\infty$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Say:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\infty$$

I know intuitively that for a large enough $n$:

$$a_n > b_n$$

So I would think that it be true to say that if:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n= L$$

Then:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n > L$$

My question is am I valid in my assumptions, and is there any way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You aren't. Look at $a_n = -n$ and $b_n = -1$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{-n}{-1} = \infty$$

Your intuitive approach is wrong in this case. For $n > 1$ we have $a_n < b_n$.

---

For positive sequences it's true that $\lim a_n > \lim b_n$, cause by definition:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \infty \Rightarrow (\forall M \in \mathbb{R})(\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N})(M <\frac{a_n}{b_n} \Leftrightarrow^* M\cdot b_n < a_n)
$$

Take big $M$ and notice that $b_n < M b_n < a_n \Rightarrow b_n < a_n$ for all $n > n_0$. So limit of $(a_n)$ cannot be smaller than $b_n$.

*Notice, that I used here, that $b_n > 0$!

Comment: What if my sequence was strictly positive, and replaced  the greater than with  "greater then or equal"

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Then it will be true. But it's absolutely other question.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Both sequences have limit $0$. But $a_n/b_n\to\infty$.